# C++ Object of User-Defined Type Returned in CPU Register. How Do Instance Methods Work?

Tags: c++, calling-convention

I know that when I call an instance method, object address is assigned to 'this' hidden pointer parameter.
In this way the method can access to the instance variables of the current object, unlike static methods don't have this parameter and so cannot refere to the current instance.

So my question is:

When an small object is returned in CPU Register (tipically in RAX Register), since the object does not have an address because it is not in the memory,

- How can an instance method refere to the object ?
- what happens to 'const this' parameter ?

there is no available address in this case.

Comment: Remember that `this` is a *pointer*. One can easily pass around pointers in CPU registers. It's unlikely that a class instance as a whole will be possible to put in a register (it doesn't make much sense nor is it, as you discovered, feasible).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the method call cannot be optimized away by the compiler, it will be forced to put the object in memory and pass the address to this memory to the function.

Generally in c++ any non-observable behavior can be optimized away.
Without seeing the function definition the compiler cannot know how `this` pointer is used and must put the object in addressable memory.

See this example https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Zff5nr where object is returned in `eax` register, stored on stack, and its address is passed in `rdi` register to a member function.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It might the same problem how is  the object returned  in register, it's copied using copy constructor ? 
In this case copy constructor should use this hidden pointer parameter, and const object reference parameter ? in the same way 'this' would not have the address beacuse object is going to be copied into register ?

Comment: @Antonio Yes, the principle is the same with constructor/copy constructor calls - in the function returning the object some memory on stack will be passed to the object constructor as `this` pointer and after that it will be loaded into register before that function return.

Answer (score 0):

Actually temporaries do have address and they **are** in the memory (unless they were optimized away altogether), usually on the stack just like local variables. Temporaries are not addressable in terms of C++ but in the actual generated code compiler is free to represent them in whatever way it wants, including putting them on stack and thus making them addressable.

You shouldn't think too literally about language constructs when comparing them to the code that is actually generated. For example, `this` pointer might not even exist at all as a pointer if the method you are calling was actually inlined by the compiler. As for the `const this`, constness is a purely compile-time notion which only helps compiler to decide which optimizations it can perform, however, it is not by any means enforced in run-time.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It might the same problem how is returned object in register, it's copied using copy constructor ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a question for the compiler, not for the programmer. The language requires a `this` pointer to be available in instance methods. If an optimizing compiler decides that it can fulfill the requirement and still keeps everything in registers it is allowed to do so per the *as if* rule: the internals of the implementation do not matter provided the *obervable* behaviour is the same of what a machine following strictly the standard (with no optimization) would produce.

So unless you target a specific compiler with specific compilation options this question cannot be answered.

For example, let us look as the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

class Foo {
    int val;

public:
    Foo(int val = 0): val(val) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Foo& f);
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Foo& f) {
    out << std::hex << std::setw(2) << f.val;
    return out;
}

int main() {
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        std::cout << Foo(i);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

A compiler could easily conclude that this is a single compilation unit program: it contains `main` and uses no external references outside the standard library. And that it just resumes to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << i;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Optimizing out the whole class definition and the friend `operator <<`.

A very clever computer could even guess that as `10` is a constant expr, everything can be resolved at compile time and could generate the same code as:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << " 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I must admit that I would not be surprised by the first optimization, but I know no real compiler that would generate the second one.

Comment: So it seems me to understand, If compiler optimizes the code, no 'this' parameter is created, and instance methods can access the object without using this pointer ?